# start new ListActivity from ListActivity within tabview

Tags: android, android-intent, listactivity, tabview

i have tabview with 4 tabs and i am using TabHost to display tabs my application.
every tab is filled by another class extends from ListActivity and here is the code

```
public class TabbedActivity extends TabActivity {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tab_layout);

    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

    // Tab for Catalog
    TabSpec catalogspec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Catalog");
    catalogspec.setIndicator("Complete Catalog Fall 2012", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_catalog));
    Intent catalogIntent = new Intent(this, Category.class);
    catalogspec.setContent(catalogIntent);
// Adding all TabSpec to TabHost
    tabHost.addTab(catalogspec); // Adding catalog tab
}
```

and this the code at the other intent

```
public class Category extends ListActivity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {       
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list_of_data);
 Categories = new ArrayList<String>();
    fillListCategories();

    myListItems = new ArrayList<String>();
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Categories);
        this.setListAdapter(adapter);
}}
```

at the Listview there is list of items ,, my Point is how to set the Onclick to open another  "ListActivity" in the same Tab ?!!

Comment: have you tried inflating a view on the onClick?

Comment: no ,, actually i am so fresh in android ,, only 3 weeks ,, Could you improve me with more details ?,, i wanna keep the tab visible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Category class, add an onClickListener like so:

```
public class Category extends ListActivity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {       
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.list_of_data);
Categories = new ArrayList<String>();
fillListCategories();

myListItems = new ArrayList<String>();
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,   Categories);
    this.setListAdapter(adapter);
    this.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onItemClick( AdapterView<?> parent, View item, 
                           int position, long id) {
    mSelectedCategory = (String)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), ScreenTwo.class); 
            intent.putExtra("name", mSelectedCategory.(WHATEVER INFO YOU NEED ABOUT THE CATEGORY);
            startActivity(intent);  
  }
});
}}
```

ScreenTwo.java would look like the category class with the ListAdapter but with the information that was passed through the intent:

```
public class ScreenTwo extends ListActivity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {       
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.list_of_data);
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras(); 
    String Name = b.getString("name");
Categories = new ArrayList<String>();
fillListCategories();

myListItems = new ArrayList<String>();
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,    Categories);
    this.setListAdapter(adapter);
}}
```

Comment: i am trying it now , but i have another questions ,,
how to set the raw in the list view by Object has 5 values ,, i am already using adapter ,, and when i use the class extends from activity it worked fine but when i used extends listactivity ,, it did not display any thing ??

Comment: i'm sorry i don't quite understand your question

Comment: the second intent the category should be redirecting to is List view but the list items isn't strings ,, it's Object of Project ,, this project have 5 values i get and set thier values using a class and i fill the data using adapter 
now , how can i fill the listview rows with this adapter data ??!!

Comment: yeah inflating a view is a view on top of the current screen so it will do that :(